# Swift. Наложение view на видео поток

Tags: swift, видео

День добрый. Возникла необходимость наложения данных(вотермарка не подходит, тк значения во view изменяются) на видео поток. В данный момент я вытягиваю из previewLayer картинку камеры ложу ее во ImageView там накладываю свои данные, делаю снапшот этой ImageView и собираю короткие видео, которые в последствии собираю в одно. Но это очень сильно нагружает устройство, плюс много точек отказа и соответственно частые краши. Прошу подсказать каким образом я могу ложить слой из view сразу на видео поток. Спасибо за ваши ответы.

Comment: посмотрите, возможно будет полезным https://www.raywenderlich.com/6236502-avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos, возможно получится сделать через рендеринг с оверлеями

Comment: Спасибо. Это я смотрел, там идет работа с уже записанным видео, мне же нужно уже на выходе иметь видео с титрами

Comment: вы хотите накладывать титры в процессе записи? Объясните подробнее что конкретно вам нужно сделать

Comment: День добрый, да. Нужно в процессе записи накладывать титры() тк там динамические данные и уже на выходе получать видео с титрами

Comment: добавьте в вопрос код, который у вас используется сейчас и желательно ссылку на туториал, по которому делали